# spring 3 configuration without transaction manager

Tags: spring, configuration, transactions

How to not use (disable) transaction manager in spring configuration?

I'm doing simple app that will add rows to database, so no need in any transactions.
So, is it possible configure in xml, not to create any transaction managers?

PS: i use hibernate if this matters anyhow.

Answer (score 2):

If you don't configure a Transaction Manager, neither will Spring. Just don't add any `<tx:>` tags and don't configure any `PlatformTransactionManager` beans (in your case [`HibernateTransactionManager`](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/javadoc-api/index.html?org/springframework/orm/hibernate3/HibernateTransactionManager.html)).